# Prove that the n-th derivative of a polynomial is the constant of the highest degree term times n!

Tags: polynomials, proof-writing

I want to prove that the n-th derivative of f(x), where f(x) is defined as follows:
$$
f(x) = a_nx^n $$
is equal to
$$
(n!)(a_n)
$$
I'm trying to do this by induction, and I my base case is for n = 0.
$$
\text{Let n=0}
\\ f(x) = a_0x^0
\\ f^{(n)}(x)= (0!)(a_0)
\\ f^{(n)}(x) = (a_0)
\\ \text{This works!}
$$
I'm having trouble with my induction step, where I prove that it works for n+1.
So according to what I'm inducting upon, the following is true
$$
f^{(n)}(x) = ((n+1)!)(a_{n+1})
$$
But how do I prove this? I can't just take derivatives because I don't know what n is. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

You assume the $n$th derivative of $a_n x^n$ is $n! a_n$.

You want to prove the $(n+1)$st derivative of $a_{n+1} x^{n+1}$ is $(n+1)! a_{n+1}$. The $(n+1)$st derivative can be obtained by taking one derivative, and then taking the $n$th derivative.

If you take one derivative, you have $(n+1) a_{n+1} x^n$. Then applying the statement in my first sentence with $a_n:= (n+1)a_{n+1}$ shows that the $n$th derivative of this is $n! a_n = n! (n+1) a_{n+1} = (n+1)! a_{n+1}$.

Comment: Oh god that makes so much more sense. Thank you so much!